# Is the public ip address on azure only bound to one virtual machine?

Tags: azure, networking

I just learned Azure Cloud Server. After creating the machine, it assigned me an ipv4 address. We all know that IPv4 addresses are limited. Are these limited addresses sufficient for Azure cloud allocation?

Is the public ip address on azure only bound to one virtual machine?

[image]

Comment: yes the public ip address  is only bound to one virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to a VM from the internet, the VM must have a public IP address associated to it. Microsoft Azure by default assigns a dynamic public IP address to a newly-created VM unless we change it to be static.
If you stop the VM(deallocate the vm) The Ip address will change.if you want to have the same IP you need to change the assignment type to static(The address doesn't change until the public IP address resource it's assigned to is deleted, or the assignment method is changed to dynamic) from Dynamic.

Please check this for better understanding about Ip Address allocation and limits in azure
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface-addresses